# Getting error while supplying parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting the following error while supplying parameters to a stored procedure:

> Procedure or function 'ismovieexists' expects parameter '@movie_name', which was not supplied

and the same error message for the procedure `insert_values_in_movie_master`..

```
public int add_movie(mymovie objmymovie)
{ 
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring);
    cn.Open();
    //SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ismovieexists", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie_name", objmymovie.MOVIE_NAME);
    SqlParameter d = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.Int);
    d.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(d);
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int i = (int)cmd.Parameters["@d"].Value;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

        cmd1.Connection = cn;
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.CommandText = "insert_values_in_movie_master";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie_name", objmymovie.MOVIE_NAME);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating", objmymovie.RATING);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@realease_year", objmymovie.REALEASE_YEAR);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starcast", objmymovie.STARCAST);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", objmymovie.LANGUAGE);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@display_home", objmymovie.DISPLAY_HOME);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@block_status", objmymovie.BLOCK_STATUS);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_of_copies", objmymovie.no_of_copies);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOVIE_category", objmymovie.MOVIE_category);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOVIE_flag", objmymovie.MOVIE_FLAG);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return i;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is objmymovie.MOVIE_NAME non-null?

Comment: Perhaps the gods are upset with your poor naming conventions? But seriously, attach the SQL Profiler and look at the SQL actually being used. You may see something interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the parameter @Movie_Name exist in your Stored Procedures?  If the parameter does exist it's likely that you are not passing a value to objmymovie.MOVIE_NAME